# How to get & display specific values from array of objects in MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

I have an array of users that contains objects for each user with full name, id, role, etc. Said users have a paramater: user_machines that it's array filled with objects in itself, and i want to get & display specific values from each object of this array. More specifically, it goes like this:
I display all users, and if the user has user_machines array with objects in it, i want to display for example the machine_name of said object.

At this time, my query looks like this:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::with('userMachines')->get();
        return response()->json(
            [
                'status' => 'success',
                'users' => $users->toArray()
            ],
            200
        );
    }
```

It get's all the information i need, but i dont know how to sort it.
Here's my getUsers mixin:

```
export const getUsers = {
  methods: {
    getUsers() {
      axios
        .get("users")
        .then(res => {
          this.users = res.data.users;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

And here's my initialization method:

```
 methods: {
    initialize() {
      this.users = [
        {
          id: "",
          full_name: "",
          username: "",
          role: "",
          division: "",
          center: "",
          machines: "",
          user_machines: []
        }
      ];
    },
```

Here's the Data Table:

```
            <v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="users"
              :key="users.id"
              :search="search || radio"
              hide-actions
              class="elevation-1"
            >
              <template v-slot:items="props">
                <td class="text-xs-left">
                  <v-avatar :size="30" color="grey lighten-4">
                    <img :src="avatar">
                  </v-avatar>
                </td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.full_name }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.role }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.division }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.center }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.user_machines }}</td>
                <td class="justify-right layout ml-3">
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn color="#009af9" flat @click="editItem(props.item)">ВИЖ</v-btn>
                </td>
              </template>
              <template v-slot:footer>
                <td :colspan="headers.length">
                  <v-btn color="#009af9" class="getMoreButton" large dark>GET MORE</v-btn>
                </td>
              </template>
              <template v-slot:no-data>
                <v-alert
                  :value="true"
                  color="error"
                  icon="warning"
                >Sorry, nothing to display here :(</v-alert>
                <v-btn color="#009af9" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
```

Here's how it looks in a get request in Telescope:

```
users: [
{
id: 1,
full_name: "SomeDude",
username: "SomeDude",
role: "admin",
division: "asdf",
center: "asdf",
created_at: "2019-05-25 10:24:17",
updated_at: "2019-05-25 10:24:17",
user_machines: [
{
id: 1,
machine_number: 2143,
machine_name: "FirstMachine",
machine_division: "FirstMachine"",
machine_center: "FirstMachine"",
machine_speed: "FirstMachine"",
created_at: "2019-05-25 10:24:17",
updated_at: "2019-05-25 10:24:17",
pivot: {
user_id: 1,
machine_id: 1
}
},
{
id: 2,
machine_number: 2241,
machine_name: "SecondMachine",
machine_division: "SecondMachine",
machine_center: "SecondMachine",
machine_speed: "SecondMachine",
created_at: "2019-05-25 10:24:17",
updated_at: "2019-05-25 10:24:17",
pivot: {
user_id: 1,
machine_id: 2
}
},
{
id: 3,
machine_number: 2341,
machine_name: "ThirdMachine",
machine_division: "ThirdMachine",
machine_center: "ThirdMachine",
machine_speed: "ThirdMachine",
created_at: "2019-05-25 10:24:17",
updated_at: "2019-05-25 10:24:17",
pivot: {
user_id: 1,
machine_id: 3
}
}
```

I would really appreciate some help and some directions on what to read on the subject from more expirienced developers.
I'm using Laravel, Vue, MySQL.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to show the code you have already for displaying the information?

Comment: @RossWilson Hello sir, i have updated my post with my getUsers() & initalize() methods.

Comment: Do you have the HTML for your component as well?

Comment: Yes, i have a Vuetify table that i can display the data in, but at this time i'm displaying the entire user_machines array, and i dont know how to only display user_machines->machine_name.

Comment: If you can show the HTML and the rest of the code for your component that would be a big help.

Comment: @RossWilson Hello sir, thank you for taking the time to help me out. I added the entire data-table,
``` 
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.user_machines }}</td>
``` 
Is where i'm getting the entire array, how can i extract values values from the array's objects ?

Comment: Thanks. Are you wanting to display all of the `machine_name`s or just the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to display the `machine_name` then you'll either need to loop through them using [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html):

replace

```
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.user_machines[0].machine_name }}</td>
```

with

```
<td class="text-xs-left">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="user_machine in props.item.user_machines" v-text="user_machine.machine_name"></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

Obviously you can use different markup instead of the unordered list (`</ul>`) if you want to.

---

Or if you're only wanting to display the first one then you could do something like:

```
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.user_machines[0].machine_name }}</td>
```

Comment: Again sir, thank you for taking time to help me out with my problem. I'm sure your solution is correct, but i'm going to try it tomorrow, it's getting late now :) Thanks again, you rock!